# Minor question about Segmented Code Cache (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/197)

Tags: java, jvm, java-11, jit, java-16

I see that this JEP (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/197) introduced 3 types of code caches.

The most obvious one to me is `-XX:NonNMethodCodeHeapSize`. This is the one that deals with JVM internal data.

What I do not understand is what is the difference between `NonProfiledCodeHeapSize` and `ProfiledCodeHeapSize`. That document says that:

> Tiered compilation also introduces a new compiled code type: instrumented compiled code (profiled code).

My understanding is that "instrumented" here means "with counters", so kind of logic to assume that this is really `C1` compiled code? And the other one is `C2`?

Comment: Instrumented means that code was inserted from performance monitoring (profiling).
Unless you are actively profiling your code I don't think you'd want that option in production.

Comment: @AminM read the answer provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Tiered Compilation, *profiled code* means JIT-compiled methods that collect execution statistics (counters and type information), which can be used later for recompilation on a different tier.

*Non-profiled code* is not only C2 code. It also includes compiled wrappers for native methods, as well as methods compiled by C1 without execution statistics ([Tier 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134037/whats-this-new-column-in-xxprintcompilation-output/41154126#41154126)), e.g. simple methods like getters/setters that will not benefit from recompilation.

See [`codeBlob.hpp`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/57df0dbc45914969df34e6f42b6c815785e11048/src/hotspot/share/code/codeBlob.hpp#L41):

```c
// CodeBlob Types
// Used in the CodeCache to assign CodeBlobs to different CodeHeaps
struct CodeBlobType {
  enum {
    MethodNonProfiled   = 0,    // Execution level 1 and 4 (non-profiled) nmethods (including native nmethods)
    MethodProfiled      = 1,    // Execution level 2 and 3 (profiled) nmethods
    NonNMethod          = 2,    // Non-nmethods like Buffers, Adapters and Runtime Stubs
    All                 = 3,    // All types (No code cache segmentation)
    NumTypes            = 4     // Number of CodeBlobTypes
  };
};
```

Comment: thank you, I was really looking into the source code (usually comments there are _very_ helpful), but could not find where it was.